# $.getJSON always failing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, getjson

Apologies if this has been answered before but I couldn't find what I was looking for. So, I use $.getJSON to send some variables to a php file. The file returns success as true but for some reason always triggers the .fail function.

The weird thing is, it all works fine on my laptop, just not on the computer at university. Connection to the database is fine, like I said everything works and it returns all the correct data but doesn't trigger the success function.

JQuery:

```
function request_user_review() {

    $.getJSON("user_review_list.php", success_user_review).fail(fail_user_review);

}

function success_user_review(response) {
    if (response.success) {

        var user_review_list = "";
        $("#user_reviews .review_cafe").remove();
        $("#user_reviews .review").remove();
        $("#user_reviews .rating").remove();
        $("#user_reviews .review_choice").remove();


        for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
            var review_cafe = '<tr id="row_' + response.rows[i].id + '"><td class="review_cafe">'
                + response.rows[i].cafe + '</td>';
            var review = '<td class="review">'
                + response.rows[i].review + '</br>Review left: ' + response.rows[i].date + '</td>';
            var rating = '<td class="rating">'
                + response.rows[i].rating + '/5</td>';
            var review_choice = '<input type="hidden" class="cafe_id" value="' +  response.rows[i].cafe_id + '" /><td class="review_choice"><button   onclick="request_edit(this.id)" id="edit_' + response.rows[i].id + '" class="btn_edit">Edit</button><button onclick="request_delete_review(this.id)" id="delete_' + response.rows[i].id + '" class="btn_delete">Delete</button></td></tr>';

            user_review_list += review_cafe + review + rating + review_choice;
        }
        $("#user_reviews").html(user_review_list).trigger("create").trigger("refresh");
    } else {
        $("#review_message").html("Review failed to be  loaded!").trigger("create").trigger("refresh");
    }
}

function fail_user_review() {
    $("#review_message").html("Connection down?").trigger("create").trigger("refresh");
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php //user_review_list.php
require_once "sql.php"; //connection to database and query is handled here
require_once "logged_in.php";

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

$session_id = $_SESSION['userid'][0];

$result = array();
$result['success'] = false;
$query = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE user = $session_id;";

if ($result_set = Sql::query($query)) {
    $result['success'] = true;
    $result['message'] = "Your Reviews" ;
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result_set);
    $result['rows'] = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i<$rows; $i++) {
        $tmpRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
        $php_date = strtotime($tmpRow['date']);
        $formatted_php_date = date('M d, Y', $php_date );
        $tmpRow['date'] = $formatted_php_date;

        $result['rows'][$i] = $tmpRow;
    }

} else {
    $result['message'] = "Failed to read Reviews" ;
}

print(json_encode($result));
```

Thanks
James

Comment: Shouldn't `print` be `echo`?

Comment: And in the fail function there are several arguments that indicate what the error was, did you look at those ?

Comment: @tymeJV print is fine in php

Comment: @JamesF what is the status code ?

Comment: @JamesF js and php are in the same folder. can you give console log and network status value i.e 200, 404, 500.etc

Comment: @lagbox I'm not sure if this is correct (beginner at JQuery) but if i add a breakpoint at the fail function and view whats happening in the JQuery it does say error 200, parsererror.

Comment: @JamesF, the `parseerror` means it doesn't like your JSON. Use http://jsonlint.com/ to see the response data to make sure it's valid JSON and if it's not, use `JSON.parse(response)`.

Comment: @gfish3000 right I see, thanks! On my latop it is succeeding, is there any reason why it only gets a `parsererror` on the PC? The code is identical.

Comment: @JamesF, without seeing your setup myself, I could only speculate. Are you using the same editors, the same version of PHP and WAMP/XMAPP or whatnot?

Comment: @gfish3000 My laptop is on netbeans 7.4, php is 5.5.11 and xampp is 1.8.3. The university is on netbeans 7.3.1, php is 5.5.3 and it runs on a linux web server of some description. Is that any help?

Comment: @gfish3000 I also get the error message: "Unexpected token W"

Comment: @JamesF that means you're trying to parse something that's already JSON. My earlier statement about parsing JSON is not going to be of much help here because you're not just getting back a string that needs to be converted to JSON (which you really shouldn't be with `$.getJSON()` but I was just trying to make sure), you're getting back a JSON with an invalid encoding somewhere along the line, so trying to parse it won't help you. Validate your JSON first and foremost.

Comment: @gfish3000 Thanks, you've really enlightened me. Could you please write that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @JamesF, well thank you! All set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages you get mean you're trying to parse something that's already JSON. My earlier statement about parsing JSON is not going to be of much help here because you're not just getting back a string that needs to be converted to JSON -- which you really shouldn't be with `$.getJSON()`.

You're getting back a JSON with an invalid encoding somewhere along the line, so trying to parse it won't help you. Validate your JSON first and foremost (the error could be due to your differing server settings between machines) using [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com), and continue from there.